# How do I find residues at simple poles?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 105, he state the following definition:

[image]

Afterwards on page 113 he made the following proposition:

[image]

So if the pole is simple at $z=a$, i.e., we have $m=1$, how can we find $Res(f,a)$? Using the proposition $Res(f;a)=g(a)$, but $g(z)$ is not defined for $z=a$.

I realized this problem when I tried to find the residue of the function $e^z/\sin z$ at $0$.

Comment: Isn't it impossible to have a pole of order 0 ? That would mean that $f(z)(z-a)^0=f(z)$ doesn't have a singularity at $z=a$ according to the first definition, which is nonsense.

Comment: @H.Potter I'm sorry, I meant $m=1$, I've already edited my question.

Comment: Oh yeah right. But then, there is no problem in using the formula given in Proposition 2.4. You have that the residue is equal to $(z-a)f(z)$ evaluated in $z=a$.

Comment: @H.Potter You need to take a limit there.

Comment: @H.Potter yes, unfortunately there is a problem. Note that $g(z)=(z-a)f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z=a$, so it's not defined at this point.

Comment: @zhw. Hi, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @user42912: $g$ has a removable singularity at $z=a$, i.e. it can be continued analytically to a function $\tilde g$ which is defined and holomorphic in $a$ as well. Frequently, the new function $\tilde g$ is called $g$ as well. In other words, $g(a)$ is *defined* as the limit of $g(z)$ for $z \to a$.

Comment: @MartinR This explains everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(From my above comment:)*

$g$ has a removable singularity at $z=a$, i.e. it can be continued analytically to a function $\tilde g$ which is defined and holomorphic in $a$ as well. Frequently, the new function $\tilde g$ is called $g$ as well. In other words, $g(a)$ is *defined* as the limit of $g(z)$ for $z \to a$.